# PHP Switch With Interweaved code

Tags: php

Quick question, I know some people are dead against interweaved code but I have a question relating to using the PHP `switch` `case` with interweaving. It was always something that was straight forward in classic ASP but not sure how it works with php.

It's designed in a way that certain parts of the GUI display or hide based on prior requests but don't want to shove all the html into php echo blocks so the visual layout is still easy to be changed and maintained.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

for example what is standard:

```
<?php
        $pagecase = 'empty';
if(isset($_GET["view"]))
    $pagecase = $_GET["view"];

switch($pagecase)
{
    default:
        $pagecase = "Option 1 Content";
        break;
    case 'now':
        $pagecase = "Option 2 Content";
        break;
    case 'past':
        $pagecase = "Option 3 Content";
        break;
} ?>
```

Vs what I want to do...

```
<?php
        $pagecase = 'empty';
if(isset($_GET["view"]))
    $pagecase = $_GET["view"];

switch($pagecase)
{
    default:
        $pagecase = "Option 1 Content";
?>
<p>some html code here for Option 2</p>
<img src="//www.example.com/img.gif">

<?php
        break;
    case 'now':
        $pagecase = "Option 2 Content";
?>
<p>some html code here for Option 2</p>
<img src="//www.example.com/img.gif">

<?php
        break;
    case 'past':
?>
<p>some html code here for Option 3</p>
<img src="//www.example.com/img.gif">

<?php
        break;
} ?>
```

Comment: What is the problem or the question? If this would be good design or if it will work? It will work, but I'd put the output into a seperate function which does the output) that you pass the changing params to.

Comment: btw: `default` would need to be the last option.

Comment: @Jeff Sorry... The problem is that is doesn't work when the code is split apart, like in the what I want to do section, but works when it's bundled into one codeblock. I know ideally it's not a fantastic design, I'm feeling it is more an `if` / `else` scenario. Would you agree?